# Support for Cauchy’s principal value of $1/x$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value, support-function

I'm trying to find support for Cauchy’s principal value of $1/x$ given by

$$\left\langle PV(1/x), \phi \right\rangle = PV \int \frac{1}{x}\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int _{|x| > \epsilon } \frac{1}{x} \phi(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
I use it
is distribution, but need support, because  distributional derivate is $L^{1}_{loc}$ and  i use it.

If $u$ is distribution in $X$ then the support of $u$, denoted $\mathrm{supp}$  $u$, is the set of points in $X$ having no open neighborhood to which the restriction of $u$ is $0$.

Comment: It should not be too difficult. Can you state the definition of the support of a distribution?

Comment: Added the definition, consider $X= \mathbb{R}$ @CalvinKhor

Comment: If you take an open $U \subseteq (0,\infty),$ what is the restriction of $\operatorname{PV}\frac{1}{x}$ to $U$?

Comment: restriction no null, @md2perpe. I don't think I understand, would it be the integral of $\epsilon$ to $\infty$, of the function above with limit tends to zero? Is the support $(\epsilon, \infty)$?

Comment: If $\phi$ has support in $(0,\infty)$ will $\langle \operatorname{PV}\frac{1}{x}, \phi \rangle$ vanish?

Comment: No, but if $\phi$ has support in complement support $\mathrm{PV} \frac{1}{x}$ @md2perpe

Comment: So the action of $\operatorname{PV}\frac{1}{x}$ will *not* vanish if $\phi$ has support in $(0,\infty).$ Neither will it vanish if $\phi$ has support in $(-\infty,0).$ This means that both $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0),$ so $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is part of the support. But this is an open set. The support is closed. Therefore the closure of it, which is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ is part of the support. Thus, the support is $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Could consider $\mathrm{PV} \frac{1}{x}$ defined in some open of $\mathbb{R}$, hence support would be closure, because support is closed, is my statement correct?@md2perpe